# What does this sentence convey to you - "We will reply you after discussion with my manager and/or head of department."

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Does this sentence - "We will reply you after discussion with **my manager** and/or head of department" conveys that -

1) I am writing from the executive's point of view i.e. I will reply to you after discussing with **my manager** ; OR

2) I am writing from a superior's point of view i.e. I will reply to you after discussing with **MY manager**....

Comment: It tells me that English is not your native language.

Comment: Yes, English is not our native language but this is the first time I got queried by my superior on the usage of "my manager". She thinks in this sentence that I am referring her as my staff and not showing respect to her.

Comment: "We will reply you" is wrong.  Nothing implies that you are writing from a superior's "point of view".

Comment: @coco what did that person suggest as a better alternative?

Comment: Your superior is wrong in that "my manager" refers to your superior (usually your immediate superior), and does not in any way imply that that person is "your staff".  There are other contexts where a upper-level bigwig might say something like "the manager of that project" and be referring to his staff, but that would not be the assumption in the general case.

Comment: As correct as @HotLicks is, don't go to your manager and say "You're wrong". Your manager may take take that as a sign of respect.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. My superior suggested that I use her name instead of 'manager' in the sentence.

Comment: The word *my* can be used in both ways. To say "this is my office" can mean "I own this office", but it can also mean "this is the office assigned to me". Here, however, the bare term "my manager" naturally reads as "the person who I report to". To make it mean "the person who reports to me but who manages other people", that meaning must come from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My" can go either way in chain of command contexts - master and servant might with equal propriety refer to each other as my servant and my master - but without further context "my manager" or "my supervisor" invariably points upward in standard English.

Outside the scope of your question, but I would try to avoid replies which cast you in the role of a supernumerary. You might try asking your manager what she thinks an appropriate reply would be, then reply on your own authority. If inquirer wants to elevate to your manager then you know they will get the right answer - and be less likely to doubt you in the future.